# Reading header from kafka using apache storm

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm

We have a use-case where we need to read message headers from kafka using apache storm and pass it to downstream bolt. In storm documentation , there is no mention of how to pass kafka headers to storm topology. is anyone has figured out how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `setRecordTranslator` while building spout.
Example:

```
return KafkaSpoutConfig.builder(
        "<bootstrap-servers>", "topic-to-consume")
        .setRecordTranslator((r) -> new Values(r.topic(), r.partition(), r.offset(), r.key(),  r.value(), r.headers()), new Fields("topic", "partition", "offset", "key", "value", "headers"))
        .build();
```

Now, in your Bolt's `execute` you would be able to access all the fields above including the headers, something like this:

```
public class MyNewBolt extends BaseRichBolt {

   @Override
   public void execute(Tuple tuple) {

      RecordHeaders messageHeaders = (RecordHeaders) tuple.getValueByField("headers");
      Iterator headerIterater = messageHeaders.iterator();
      while (headerIterater.hasNext()) {
         Header header = (Header) headerIterater.next();
         String headerKey = header.key();
         byte[] headerBytes = header.value();
         String headerValue = new String(headerBytes);
         System.out.println("Header Key: " + headerKey);
         System.out.println("Header Value: " + headerValue);

      }
}

}
```